# Django script fails to save model instance, complains a field with a value is null...?

Tags: django, django-models

I'm doing the most simple of operations and getting an error...  I'm pulling a model instance, updating some fields, and then saving those fields that I modified.  I get back an error saying that a null value is not allowed for one of those fields.  That boolean field has a default in models.py, AND in the database, AND it's one of the fields I'm saving a value for.

models.py

```
class Person(TimeStampedModel):
    # ...
    precertified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

logic.py

```
try:
    print('Getting Person %s...' % record['nurturing_id'])
    person = Person.objects.get(pk=record['nurturing_id'])
except Person.DoesNotExist:
    person = None
    print('Person %s no longer exists.' % record['nurturing_id'])
if person:
    person.uncorrected_address = person.address
    person.uncorrected_address_line_two = person.address_line_two
    person.uncorrected_city = person.city
    person.uncorrected_state = person.state
    person.uncorrected_zipcode = person.zipcode
    person.address = record['Address']
    person.address_line_two = record['Address Line Two']
    person.city = record['City']
    person.state = record['State']
    person.zipcode = record['Zipcode']
    person.precertified = True
    person.precertified_check = now
    person.save(update_fields=['precertified', 'address', 'address_line_two', 'city', 'state', 'zipcode', 'uncorrected_address', 'uncorrected_address_line_two', 'uncorrected_city', 'uncorrected_state', 'uncorrected_zipcode', ])
```

Using `person.save()` also fails.

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/sites/easy/apps/JSM/logic.py", line 1349, in precertify_contacts
    person.save(update_fields=['precertified', 'address', 'address_line_two', 'city', 'state', 'zipcode', 'uncorrected_address', 'uncorrected_address_line_two', 'uncorrected_city', 'uncorrected_state', 'uncorrected_zipcode', ])
  File "/Environments/easy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/model_utils/tracker.py", line 134, in save
    ret = original_save(**kwargs)
  File "/Environments/easy/src/easyapps/nurturing/models.py", line 248, in save
    super(Person, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Environments/easy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 708, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/Environments/easy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 736, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "/Environments/easy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 801, in _save_table
    forced_update)
  File "/Environments/easy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 851, in _do_update
    return filtered._update(values) > 0
  File "/Environments/easy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 645, in _update
    return query.get_compiler(self.db).execute_sql(CURSOR)
  File "/Environments/easy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1149, in execute_sql
    cursor = super(SQLUpdateCompiler, self).execute_sql(result_type)
  File "/Environments/easy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 848, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Environments/easy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/Environments/easy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Environments/easy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 95, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/Environments/easy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

IntegrityError: null value in column "precertified" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (165771, 2016-11-16 01:48:15.613901+00, 2017-02-10 14:09:34.11354+00, General Manager, Prospect, null, , email@email.com, 1671 SOME RD, None, LINTHICUM, MD, 21090-9999, null, null, null, null, null, null, 999999, null, null, null, null, , Company Name, null, null, null, null, null, null, , , null, null, null, f, null, null, null, 005o0000001fAnfAAE, , Market Specific Mass Email, null, null, 00Qo0000006RxoUEAS, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, f, null, null, 2017-02-10 14:09:34.061993+00, 1671 Some Rd, null, Linthicum, MD, 21090).
```

I've got to be missing something silly.  Someone smack me with the cluebat please?

Comment: looks really strange, did you try to print(person.precertified) before person.save() ? also check if there's a save() method for this class in models.py; take a look at signals - eg pre-save

Comment: @Satevg: Yes!  I can't believe I missed that.  I had a custom save method that was based on a previous version of the model, setting precertification to None if the address was changed.  *slaps forehead* Thanks!

Comment: Added comment as answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks really strange, did you try to `print(person.precertified)` before `person.save()` ?

Also check if there's a `save()` method for this class in `models.py`; take a look at signals - eg `pre-save`

Answer (score 0):

Just as @Satevg suggested, I had a custom save method based on a previous version of the model.  It set precertification to None if any of the address fields were changed (it wasn't boolean in the previous version).

(@Satevg - if you want to re-post your comment as an answer I'll accept it so you get some points.)